# How to get date: one month away from a specific date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I know that I can get the date from today such as

> select CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months';

But what if I need the first date specified. Something like

> select '2017-05-08 00:00:00' - INTERVAL '1 months'?

I tried different things and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
select '2017-05-08 00:00:00'::DATE - '1 month'::INTERVAL
                             /\
                              |
                              cast as date
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=dc22740bce0cc647cdc05373d3f15a64)**

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`'2017-05-08 00:00:00'` is a string literal. You need to convert it to a date, e.g., by using `to_date`:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2017-05-08','yyyy-mm-dd') - INTERVAL '1 months'
```